# multiple 2D 'and'-statements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'd like to compare multiple, 2-dimensional logical variables with each other. I can think of solving this problem with a loop, however I suspect it could be done with inbuilt functions.

Do I need an extra function or can this be achieved using inbuilt functions?

Code:

```
a=logical(randi([0 1],5,5));
b=logical(randi([0 1],5,5));
c=logical(randi([0 1],5,5));
%d,e,f... etc.
and(a,b,c)
```

However this gives you an error:

```
Error using  & 
Too many input arguments.
```

Working loop solution:

```
%example function to solve this
function out=extended_and(varargin)
  out=varargin{1};
  for ind=2:numel(varargin)
      out=out & varargin{ind};
  end
end
```

Comment: Use and operator : `a&b&c`.

Comment: @rahnema. That's exactly equivalent to what OP has

Comment: @user2305193. What is the actual problem? What's wrong with the code you show?

Comment: `and` only accepts two arguments.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm aware you can chain commands, I'm asking if I have to write a function to do that or if there's maybe a smarter way to solve this using in-built functions

Comment: I actually like your `extended_and` function. I would just write the loop as `for ind=2:numel(varargin)`, because it's slightly simpler.

Comment: @CrisLuengo agreed, changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a`, `b`, `c` (`d`, `e`, `f`) are all related, they should be in the same array. Something like:

```
L(:,:,1)=logical(randi([0 1],5,5));
L(:,:,2)=logical(randi([0 1],5,5));
L(:,:,3)=logical(randi([0 1],5,5));
%L(:,:,4)... etc.
%or, more simply:
% L = logical(randi([0 1], 5, 5, 327)); or however may arrays you want
```

Then you can use `all`:

```
R = all(L, 3);
```

If you **have** to have `a`, `b`, `c`, ... you can concatenate them first:

```
L = cat(3, a, b, c);
```

Comment: I tried that, but without using the dimension argument in the `all` function. It's elegant, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Can this approach be extended if it's not actual variables `a,b,c` but it's a function argument `varargin` (or any cell array for that matter)?

Comment: Sure, you just have to convert your cell array to a comma-separated list. So if you have a cell array `C` of same-sized 2d arrays, `L = cat(3, C{:});`

Comment: awesome. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I approve of this answer, but wanted to add that, for large arrays, this would be slower than calling `and` in a loop. A loop is no longer slow in MATLAB, and will avoid unnecessary copies of the data.